# JavaScript - Need sum of total price from all rows in total input but it concatenates the values together instead of adding them

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to sum the total price of all rows in total. But it can not add the value it just concatenates the values. Here's PHP that generates the HTML:

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($db->getRecordSet($sqlTrRecord) as $row){$counter += 1; ?>
    <tr id="temTr" class="banktblhd">
      <td width="5"> <?php echo($counter); ?> </td>


      <td class="w10"> <input type="number" name="item_code" id="item_code" class="form-control" value="<?php echo($row['item_code']); ?>" readonly  /></td>
      <td class="w10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="<?php echo($row['item_name']); ?>" readonly /> </td>
      <td class="w10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" id="description" value="<?php echo($row['description']); ?>" readonly /></td>
      <td class="w10"><input type="number" class="form-control" name="availableQty" id="availableQty" value="<?php echo($row['quantity']); ?>" readonly  /></td>
      <td class="w10"><input type="number" class="form-control" name="p_cost" oninput="total(this);" id="p_cost" value="<?php echo($row['p_cost']); ?>" readonly /></td>
      <td class="w10">
        <input type="number" oninput="total(this);" class="form-control" name="quantity" id="quantity" autocomplete="off" /> </td>
      <td class="w10">
        <input type="number" oninput="total(this);" class="form-control" name="sale" id="sale" autocomplete="off" /> </td> 
      <td class="w10"><input type="number" oninput="total(this)" class="form-control" name="total_price" id="total_price" readonly />
      </td>
      <td class="w10" colspan="2"><input type="number" class="form-control"  name="total" id="total" readonly /></td>
```

and here's my JavaScript:

```
function total(element) {
    var row = element.closest("tr");
    var unitRate = row.querySelector("input[name=p_cost]");
    var qty = row.querySelector("input[name=quantity]");
    var sale = row.querySelector("input[name=sale]");

    var total_price = parseFloat(unitRate.value * qty.value) + parseFloat(sale.value);
    var total = row.querySelector("input[name=total_price]").value = total_price;

    document.getElementById("total").value += total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to get a string from the input field. Then you need to type  conversion of the string to an integer because by default it's picked as a string

Solution: `parseInt(value)`

`let num = parseInt(value)`

After that num variable can be added to any number type of variable. And it will start working.

Comment: @YakovL can you please update this so that I will be able to answere well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `document.getElementById("total").valueAsNumber` because `document.getElementById("total").value` gives you as string

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you go

```
document.getElementById("total").value += total;
```

which is the same as

```
document.getElementById("total").value = document.getElementById("total").value + total;
```

Now `document.getElementById("total").value` is a text value so the first operand is text and the second one is converted to text, tha's why you get concatenation (try `"2"+2` and `var a = "2"; a+=2` in console). So you may go

```
document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value) + total;
```

But actually I think you need

```
document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value) + total_price;
```

and don't need to create another var (`total`) at all (why do you need it?)

In fact, I think you need (instead of the last 3 lines of the `total` function [man, it should be `getTotal`, don't name functions like that!]):

```
var total_price = parseFloat(unitRate.value * qty.value) + parseFloat(sale.value);
row.querySelector("input[name=total_price]").value = total_price;
var prevTotal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("total").value);
document.getElementById("total").value = prevTotal + total_price;
```

In fact this also seems to be not a good idea: currently your `total` function is called on input so when one types `1`, 1 is added to your total, when the go on and type `10`, 10 *more* will be added, giving you `11`. If they change the value, your handler will be adding the new value keeping the previous ones.. You have to recalculate the total each time!